# How to change UTC time in my Super User profile?

Tags: support

My time zone is UTC +05.30 (Chennai,Mumbai India). Can I change the time from UTC to my local timezone in my Super User account or across all Stack Exchange accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange runs on UTC, there's no option or provision to change it.

Comment: Side note, some parts of the site will automatically detect your timezone, and provide information accordingly, such as for site events and chat.